# Ruby socket connection refused on 0.0.0.0:8080

Tags: ruby, linux, sockets

I'am learning ruby socket programming and I'am on linux OS(Ubuntu 16.04 to be exact).

The following code:

```
require 'socket'

socket = TCPSocket.new('0.0.0.0', 8080)
client = socket.accept

puts "New client! #{client}"

client.write("Hello from server")
client.close
```

is giving me the following error:

sock2.rb:3:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 8080 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from sock2.rb:3:in`new'
    from sock2.rb:3:in `'

Should I use a different IP and port? or do I have to make some sort of configuration on my unix system for the client and server to speak to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`TCPSocket.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html#method-c-new) tries to connect to the host specified in the arguments. It looks like you are trying to set up a server listening on that port, for that you should use [`TCPServer`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPServer.html)  instead:

```
socket = TCPServer.new('0.0.0.0', 8080)
```

You can then connect to this server with another client. That client could possibly use `TCPSocket`.